# Ransacker and Arel on associations fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, arel, ransack

I have `Project::Contribution` that `belongs_to` `User`, and
`User` `has_one` `User::Profile`.

`first_name` and `last_name` are fields contained in `User::Profile`

I want to create a ransacker that would allow me to filter my contributions with their user profile `first_name` and `last_name`.

How can this be achieved ?

This is what I tried so far :

```
# admin/contribution.rb
filter :user_full_name_cont

# models/user.rb
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||', parent.table[:profile_first_name], parent.table[:profile_last_name]) # error
end
```

This fails because of : `parent.table[:profile_first_name]` and `parent.table[:profile_last_name]` because I can't access the `profile` table like so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally came to a solution :

```
# models/user/profile.rb
  ransacker :full_name, formatter: proc { |v| v.mb_chars.downcase.to_s } do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('LOWER',
     [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws',
      [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' '), parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name]])])
  end

# admin/user.rb
filter :user_profile_full_name_cont
```

Comment: I got the same error but I was using InfixOperation insted of  NamedFunction. This solvd my problem. Thank you.